# Could I manipulate name of object as string and vice versa? Lazarus/Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, object, lazarus

Could I manipulate name of object as string and vice versa? Lazarus/Delphi

```
procedure mapping(objectname: string; referobject_bl:integer; referobjectname: string; shift_value: integer);
begin
  objectname.Top:=Round(Form2.Height/40);
  objectname.Width:=Round(Form2.Width/4);
  objectname.Left:=Round(Form2.Width/2-Form2.Width/4/2);
  objectname.Height:=Round(Form2.Height/32);
end;  

mapping('Form2.Label0',0,'',0);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a procedure, which locates dynamically my objects (buttons, labels and so on) on the form.  Objectname - one of arguments of this procedure.

Comment: So you're not looking for the variable name of a TObject, you want to find a TComponent on a TForm by it's "Component name", right? IF yes, then you're looking for something for this http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FindComponent_(Delphi)

Comment: You could just try to compile this to very quickly discover that this will not work.

Comment: I know that my code doesn't work. But I still have to place my objects on form dynamically, I should to send their names to procedure and then somehow work with them.

Comment: @Areso if you would like to add information to your question, you can [edit] the question.  Please don't add new code in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this will absolutely not work.  The `Name` of a component is simply a property of that object - it does not constitute any sort of reference to the underlying object.  If you want to modify an object you need to pass a reference to that object.  For example :

```
procedure mapping(ALabel : TLabel);
begin
  ALabel.Top:=20;
end;
```

Which you would call like :

```
mapping(Form1.Label0);
```

If you would like the method to work for any `TControl` you could make the declaration more broad :

```
procedure mapping(AControl : TControl);
begin
  AControl.Top:=20;
end;
```

and calling this would still work :

```
mapping(Form1.Label0);
```

since a `TLabel` is a descendent of `TControl` and all `TControl`s have a `.Top` (etc) property.

Comment: I would like to call my procedure with a few dozens objects with differents arguments (position shift, referring object, object to work with). Could I? 'Cause I started with Form2.Label0.Top:=...; (as well as Height, Left, Width), Form2.Label1.Top:=; and so on for all of them.

Comment: @Areso yes, you can.  You simply have to pass a real reference to the object rather than a string containing its name (as I've demonstrated).